# Adding annotations to an image at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to develop a simple application (C#, WinForms, Visual Studio 2013) that is capable to:

**1)** *To load an image from hard drive;*

**2)** *Add anotations to the picture and save modifications (in other words the user is able to draw strings (in any place) on the image at Run-Time).*

For loading an image I did:

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        theDialog.Title = "Open Image File";
        theDialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tiff;";
        theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(theDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

But I cannot figure out how to achieve the **second** task.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Graphis.DrawString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx) to add a text at a specified position (with the specified color, font family, font size, and so on):

```
try
{           
    var image = Image.FromFile("d:\\temp\\image.jpg");
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16.0f);
        graphics.DrawString("copyright 2014", font, Brushes.Red, new Point(10, 10));
    }
    image.Save("d:\\temp\\image_copyright.jpg");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Original image:

[image]

With the added text:

[image]

When possible (and appropriate) try always to wrap the creation of the `Graphics` object in a `using` statement. Use the [Graphics.FromImage method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) to create a graphics object from existing image (as in your case). This way the disposal of the objects that are not needed anymore will be done automatically by the framework for you. Use the `Point` object to put your text at the desired position, where `(0,0)` is the top left corner of the image.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to add the text at a custom position in your `PictureBox`, then bind the `PictureBox.MouseClick` event, convert the coordinates to client coordinates, use the converted mouse coordinates to position the text over the image and refresh the `PictureBox` control, after the image is modified:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) ? textBox.Text : "copyright 2014";
    var imageCoordinates = translateStretchImageMousePosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox.Image))
    {
        var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16.0f);
        graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, imageCoordinates);
    }
    pictureBox.Refresh();
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Because the `PictureBox` has different modes of *image sizing*, you need to calculate the click coordinates differently. How to do this is shown in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20923/Mouse-Position-over-Image-in-a-PictureBox). You could also try using the different [client coordinate translation functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229598%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offered by the .NET framework.

Comment: The point is that the user have to be capable to add strings when the application is running. He should be able to add strings anywhere by clicking the image but not in the specified point (in the code). Anyway thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code

```
FileStream FILESTRM = new FileStream(@"INPUT_FILE_PATH", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image IMG = Image.FromStream(FILESTRM);
FILESTRM.Close();
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(IMG);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
//                   Custom         Font       Text Color    Text
//                    Text          Name           ||       Position
//                     \/            \/            \/         \/
graphics.DrawString("YOUR STRING", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
b.Save(@"OUTPUT_FILE_PATH", IMG.RawFormat);
IMG.Dispose();
b.Dispose();
```

Comment: The point is that the user have to be capable to add strings when the application is running. He should be able to add strings anywhere by clicking the image but not in the specified point (in the code). Anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: You can Replace **Text Position** with position of your mouse